# Selecting only one row from duplicated values column

Tags: php, sql

```
[ title   -    date  ]
[  PHP    -  10/10/10]
[  PHP    -  10/10/11]
[  PDO    -  10/10/12]
[  ASP    -  10/10/13]
[  ASP    -  10/10/16]
[  PHP    -  10/10/18]
```

From this table when i use this query

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT title, date FROM posts WHERE title = :title ORDER BY title, date";
```

and go

```
Prepare
Execute
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
  $title = $row['title'];
  $date = $row['date'];

  echo "<div>$title</div><div>$date</div>";
 }
```

i still get all the values and not only one value with the title PHP, I only want to pick the value with the highest date

i want it to be

```
<div>ASP</div><div>10/10/16</div>
<div>PDO</div><div>10/10/12</div>
<div>PHP</div><div>10/10/18</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a simple aggregation:

```
SELECT title, MAX(date) 
FROM posts 
GROUP BY title
ORDER BY title
```

Comment: What does GROUP BY does exactly? W3School explanation doesn't make me understand a word

Comment: `GROUP BY` is similar to `DISTINCT` returning a single row from multiple rows sharing the same value, but additionally allows to apply functions like `MIN/MAX/SUM/AVG/COUNT`. In your case it returns the maximum date for each title.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only one row, use `limit 1`:

```
SELECT title, date
FROM posts
WHERE title = :title
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: So what is the usage of DISTINCT then?

Comment: If you have another question, then ask it as a question.  If you need to understand the syntax of SQL, refer to the documentation.

Comment: Still didn't work as intended, I want PHP title to be called only one time with the date of the highest one. Then the PDO will be called to next to it directly, limiting by one would make the while loop useless